# compare list and sublist linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to compare two lists like as

```cs
public class List1
{
    public string StudentCode { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

public class List2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<ListInfo> ListInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ListInfo
{
    public string StudentCode { get; set; }
    public string Mark1 { get; set; }
    public string Mark2 { get; set; }
}
```

need to check list1.student code is equal to List2.ListInfo.student code and return List1 data
    how to do this using LINQ kindly help me.

Comment: Do you have lists of such classes?

Comment: yes List1 and List2 like as IList<list1>

Comment: So yo want your `IList<List1>` to be filtered, leaving only objects that have a `StudentCode` found in  `IList<List2>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Var newList = list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2 => l2.ListInfo.Any(li => li.StudentCode == l1.StudentCode)));
```

Here you are checking if anything in the ListInfo Lists of List2 have a StudentCode that is in List1.

Comment: @SureshSankar No problem. Accept the answer if its good for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example to get matching records from `List1` and `List2` using LINQ

```
var list1 = new List<List1>();
list1.Add(new List1() { StudentCode = "s1", Department = "d1" });
list1.Add(new List1() { StudentCode = "s2", Department = "d2" });
list1.Add(new List1() { StudentCode = "s3", Department = "d3" });

var listInfo = new List<ListInfo>();
listInfo.Add(new ListInfo() { StudentCode = "s1" });
listInfo.Add(new ListInfo() { StudentCode = "s3" });

var list2 = new List<List2>();
list2.Add(new List2() { id = "1", ListInfo = listInfo });     

var filteredlist = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(l2=>l2.ListInfo.Any(y => y.StudentCode == x.StudentCode)));
```

Comment: var newList = list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2 => l2.ListInfo.Any(li => li.StudentCode == l1.StudentCode)));

Comment: @SureshSankar, ok got it. In your case list2 is `List<List2>'. have updated the code accordigly

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I think of is:

```
 List<List1> result = new List<List1>();
 foreach (var listItem in list2)
    {
      var list1Obj = list1.Where(n => listItem.ListInfo.Any(x => x.StudentCode == n.StudentCode)).FirstOrDefault();
      if(list1Obj != null)
         result.Add(list1Obj);
    }
```

Comment: var newList = list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2 => l2.ListInfo.Any(li => li.StudentCode == l1.StudentCode)));

Comment: Cool, you got a one-liner :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have an instance of List1 and List2.

```
var l1 = new List<List1>();
var l2 = new List<List2>();
var listInfos = new List<ListInfo>();

l2.ForEach(i => listInfos.AddRange(i.ListInfo));
var x =  l1.Select(i => listInfos.Any(info=>info.StudentCode == i.StudentCode));
```

Comment: I think he needs List1 to be returned

Comment: @ZavenZareyan no, `x` would now be `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Answer (score -1):

Pls give it a try the code below:

```
var result = list1.Where(p => list2.SelectMany(p1 => p1.ListInfo).Where(p2 => p2.StudentCode == p.StudentCode)).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you pls give me the more detailed errors that you are getting ?

Comment: var newList = list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2 => l2.ListInfo.Any(li => li.StudentCode == l1.StudentCode)));

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Suresh Sankar